# Virtual Network Adapter Sometimes Causes DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in Host

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns, vmware-workstation

After setting up a Virtual Network Adapter in VMWare Workstation Pro 12, I have recently been getting `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` errors in the Host OS sporadically.

What is the cause of this (Did I make a configuration error?) and is there a fix?

### Notes:

- The error does not occur within the Guest OS
- Disabling the Virtual Network Adapter in the Host OS resolves the issue
- **The Guest OS still has network connectivity (including internet) even when the Virtual Network Adapter is disabled on the host** *
- Both networks are connecting through IPv4 to the internet
- The errors appear to occur randomly and last between 1 and 5 minutes
- The DNS Cache on the Host appears to be functioning normally
- The problem occurs regardless of the power state of the Guest

** How is this even possible?*

The following appears in Windows Event Viewer (Some output is omitted):

```
Level: Warning
Source: DNS Client Events
Name resolution for the name www.example.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
```

### What I have tried so far:

- In both the Virtual Network Adapter and the Host Adapter, I have added DNS Servers from Level3, Verisign, and Google (Each individually and all at once)
- In both the Host and Guest, I have run `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /flushdns`, and `ipconfig /renew`
- In both the Host and Guest, in an elevated instance of Command Prompt, I have run `netsh winsock reset` and restarted both the Guest and Host
- In both the Host and Guest, I have disabled the Firewall and Antivirus
- On both Chrome and Firefox, I have cleared all cached data

### Network Configs:

**Guest**:

The following is what is configured inside VMWare Workstation 12 Pro:

- Network is running as NAT
- Network IP is `172.16.0.1/16`
- DHCP is Enabled, with lease IP addresses in the range of `172.16.128.0` to `172.16.255.254`
- Gateway in Guest OS is set to `172.16.0.1`
- No ports are currently forwarded
- Preferred and Alternative DNS servers are currently set to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

Output of `ipconfig /all` can be found [Here](https://pastebin.com/ZnUKYW5z)

**Host**:

Output of `ipconfig /all` can be found [Here](https://pastebin.com/ruua2ZVr) (Sensitive and irrelevant information is replaced with `#`)

### System Information:

- Host OS: Windows 10 Home (Version 1607, Build 14393.1066)*
- Guest OS: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter (Version 1607, Build 14393.1066)**
- VMWare Workstation 12 Pro (Version 12.5.5, Build 5234757)

** Host was updated from Build 14393.953 to Build 14393.1066; This did not resolve the issue*

*** Guest was updated from Build 14393.447 to Build 14393.1066; This did not resolve the issue*

Comment: You know that you should have the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter  be the host since after all it is Datacenter edition!!

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator I know, just something I was messing around with for a course I am taking.

Comment: In the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, have you installed the DNS Server role? If yes - try to remove it.

Comment: @harrymc I did not have the DNS Server Role installed. Only the mandatory Storage Service Role is installed on the Guest OS.

Comment: Does the problem only happen when the guest is powered on?

Comment: @harrymc No, it occurs regardless of the power state of the Virtual Machine. It also occurs whether the VMWare Tray Process is running or not on the Host. As long as the Virtual Network Adapter is enabled on the host, the problem will occur.

Comment: (1) What happens if you change the network of the VM to Bridged (VMnet0) and disable NAT (VMnet8)? You can use vmnetcfg.exe for that and other settings. (2) What are your DNS servers on computer and router? Try setting those of the computer to [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).